# Select option not selected

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I'm using Flask-WTF to render a form with a `Select` field with two options populated from a database. The problem is that even if I set the value of a choice, and the HTML is aparently rendered correctly the selection is not shown, look at this screenshot:

[image]

The options are stored in the DB as this:

```
select * from test_status;
 idteststatus |  status   
--------------+-----------
            1 | DRAFT
            2 | PUBLISHED
(2 rows
```

My route is this:

```
@app.route("/edittest/<idtest>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])                                                               def edittest(idtest):                                                                                                               
    test = Test.query.get(idtest)                                                                                       
    form = EditTestForm(obj=test)                                                                                       
    form.teststatus.choices = [(s.idteststatus, s.status) for s in TestStatus.query.all()]                              
    form.teststatus.data = 2                                                                                                
    if form.validate_on_submit():                                                                                               
    test = Test(                                                                                                                
            idtest = idtest,                                                                                                                                                                   
            idstatus = form.teststatus.data                                                                                                                                                
        )                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                        
        db.session.merge(test)                                                                                          
        db.session.commit()                                                                                             
        return redirect("/edittest/{idtest}".format(idtest = test.idtest))                                              
    return render_template('edittest.html',form=form, data={"idtest": test.idtest})
```

Form:

```
class EditTestForm(FlaskForm):                                                                                          
    teststatus = SelectField('Status', coerce=int)                                                                      
                                                                                                                        
    submit = SubmitField('Ok')
```

Template:

```
...
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">                                                                         
                  {{form.teststatus.label(class="form-control-label") }}                                                
                  {{form.teststatus(class='form-control')}}                                                             
              </div>   
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is line: `form.teststatus.data = 2`
It allows you to set the default value, but the consequence is that the value remains fixed at the default value, as you can see by calling the function `validate_on_submit()`.

Here's an approach that works:

Form:

```
class EditTestForm(FlaskForm):                                                                                          
    teststatus = SelectField('Status', coerce=int, choices=[(s.idteststatus, s.status) for s in TestStatus.query.all()])                                                                                                                                                                                      
    submit = SubmitField('Ok')
```

Route:

```
@app.route("/edittest/<idtest>", methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def edittest(idtest):                                                                                                                                                                    
    test = Test.query.get(idtest)                                                                                       
    form = EditTestForm(obj=test, teststatus=2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    if form.validate_on_submit():                                                                                               
        test = Test(                                                                                                                
            idtest = idtest,                                                                                                                                                                   
            idstatus = form.teststatus.data                                                                                                                                                
        )                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                    
        db.session.merge(test)                                                                                          
        db.session.commit()                                                                                             
        return redirect("/edittest/{idtest}".format(idtest = test.idtest))                                              
    return render_template('edittest.html',form=form, data={"idtest": test.idtest})
```

As you can see, I dynamically fill the `selectField` directly in the definition of the form and when rendering the form I set the `default` value.

**EDIT**:

Form:

```
teststatus = SelectField('Status', coerce=int, choices=[(s.idteststatus, s.status) for s in TestStatus.query.all()], default=2)
```

Route:

```
form = EditTestForm(obj=test)
```

Comment: Now the `teststatus=2` param is ignored. No option is selected.

Comment: which version of Flask-wtf are you using?

Comment: sorry for the delay: WTForms==2.3.1

Comment: and Flask-WTF==0.14.3

Comment: I use exactly the same versions and everything works fine for me. I've updated my answer by adding another variant of code that you can test.